Buddha’s views on women and how Buddhism views it
My professor said that it is believed in Buddhism that to attain Buddhahood, you need to be a man, so a woman needs to become a man first. Then she added that Buddha on the contrary believed that addition of one woman into the Sangha would make the Sangha last thousand years more.
Why this difference and what are the contexts behind them? What is the exact status of gender equality in Bhuddhism?

Related topic: Can the Buddha ever be a woman?

In original Pali Buddhism, there is only one Buddha for an era, called 'Sammasambuddha'; who was/is Gotama for this current era. A 'Sammasambuddha' has two essential criteria:

They attain full awakening without a teacher.

They establish the Buddha religion (sasana) in the world by revealing the Path for the four types of awakened persons.


Disciples of a 'Sammasambuddha' that attain full awakening are called 'Arahant' disciples.
The sutta MN 115 says a 'Sammasambuddha' cannot be a woman:

Aṭṭhānametaṁ anavakāso yaṁ itthī arahaṁ assa sammāsambuddho
It’s impossible for a woman to be a perfected one, a fully awakened
Buddha.
MN 115

However, Pali Buddhism never says a female disciple cannot attain fully awakening or Arahant. For example, there is an entire set of suttas called the Therīgāthā about the fully awakened Arahant female disciples of the Buddha.
The sutta AN 8.51, about the ordination of women, specifically says a woman can attain Arahant:

Bhabbo, ānanda, mātugāmo tathāgatappavedite dhammavinaye agārasmā anagāriyaṁ pabbajitvā sotāpattiphalampi sakadāgāmiphalampi anāgāmiphalampi arahattaphalampi sacchikātun
A female is able to realize the fruits of stream-entry, once-return,
non-return and perfection once she has gone forth.
AN 8.51

However, AN 8.51 also says:

Ānanda, if females had not gained the going forth from the lay life to
homelessness in the teaching and training proclaimed by the Realized
One, the spiritual life would have lasted long. The true teaching
would have remained for a thousand years. But since they have gained
the going forth, now the spiritual life will not last long. The true
teaching will remain only five hundred years.
It’s like those families with many women and few men. They’re easy
prey for bandits and thieves. In the same way, the spiritual life does
not last long in a teaching and training where females gain the going
forth.
It’s like a field full of rice. Once the disease called ‘white bones’
attacks, it doesn’t last long. In the same way, the spiritual life
does not last long in a teaching and training where females gain the
going forth.
It’s like a field full of sugar cane. Once the disease called ‘red
rot’ attacks, it doesn’t last long. In the same way, the spiritual
life does not last long in a teaching and training where females gain
the going forth.
AN 8.51

The above shows the Buddha never taught 'gender equality'.
While women can attain Arahant status, the Buddha clearly said women are not capable of maintaining the Buddha-Dhamma in the world to the same degree as men. This would probably be for the same reasons a woman cannot be a Sammāsambuddha. In short, women appear to lack spiritual authority to establish & maintain the Teachings in the world. SN 37.28 says:

Mendicants, when a man has one power he has a female under his mastery. What one power? The power of authority. Mastered by this, a female’s powers of attractiveness, wealth, relatives, children and ethical behavior do not avail her.
SN 37.28

For example, most theories about the decline & extinction of Buddhism in its birthland of India significantly refer to Buddhism's loss of royal patronage; which demonstrates the importance of being able to secure political support for Buddhism.
For example, in this video, we can watch & listen to two monks easily dismiss a Western nun. Or in this video, we can watch the same Western nun needing the help of a senior monk (because of lacking spiritual power & authority). Another example is this American womens' monastery closing down after nine years. Or this video may be difficult to take seriously.
In summary, the male element/faculty established Buddhism (because it was easier for the male element/faculty to develop dispassion towards family life of reproduction & thus leave the household life for the homeless life). It follows it is supreme virtue for bhikkhuni and laywomen to be grateful to the Buddha & his monks. Again, AN 8.51 says:

A nun, even if she has been ordained for a hundred years, should bow
down to a monk who was ordained that very day. She should rise up for
him, greet him with joined palms, and observe proper etiquette toward
him. This principle should be honored, respected, esteemed, and
venerated, and not transgressed so long as life lasts.
AN 8.51


As stated in the other answer, a woman can become a nun, can become fully liberated but cannot become a Sammasambuddha.
Ven. Sujato attributes this to social norms of the times in his comments below to MN 115 i.e. women may not be accepted as leaders. He also thinks this may be a later addition. If you look at DN 31, parents are responsible to arrange the marriage of their children. This again is based on the social norms of the times.

It is unclear why this is mentioned, and since the Chinese parallel MA
181 lacks this passage entirely, it may be a later addition. It is of
no apparent spiritual relevance, since in early Buddhist texts there
is no concept of aspiring to become a Buddha in future lives. A woman
may, of course, realize full liberation as an arahant, so the issue is
not spiritual prowess. As to the reasoning underlying the claim, in
this passage the Buddha is followed by a wheel-turning monarch, Sakka,
Māra, and Brahmā. What they all have in common is that they are
leaders. Since leaders of the time were men, perhaps it was assumed
that people would not follow a woman in that role. This reasoning
would also seem to be behind the idea that the Buddha was born either
an aristocrat or a brahmin, whichever was the leading class of the
time (DN 14:1.5.1).

Becoming a Sammasambuddha is so difficult and extremely rare that most men never achieve it either.
In the household, a wife is not like a servant but rather more like a Deputy Prime Minister or Vice President to the husband, who is the head of the household. The husband ensures livelihood and the wife takes care of the domestic front.

A husband should serve his wife as the western quarter in five ways:
by treating her with honor, by not looking down on her, by not being
unfaithful, by relinquishing authority to her, and by presenting her
with adornment.A wife served by her husband in these five ways shows
sympathy to him in five ways. She’s well-organized in her work. She
manages the domestic help. She’s not unfaithful. She preserves his
earnings. She’s deft and tireless in all her duties. A wife served by
her husband in these five ways shows sympathy to him in these five
ways. And that’s how the western quarter is covered, kept safe and
free of peril.
DN 31

Ven. Sujato added these comments to the sutta above:

Marriage is based on mutual care and respect, not on dominance and obedience.

The Buddha however intended nuns to be subordinate to monks. Again this may be based on the social norms of the times where women may not be seriously accepted as leaders.

A nun, even if she has been ordained for a hundred years, should bow
down to a monk who was ordained that very day. She should rise up for
him, greet him with joined palms, and observe proper etiquette toward
him. .....
From this day forth it is forbidden for nuns to criticize monks, but
it is not forbidden for monks to criticize nuns.
AN 8.51


My professor said that it is believed in Buddhism that to attain Buddhahood, you need to be a man, so a woman needs to become a man first.
For more-detailed answers please see this topic:

Can the Buddha ever be a woman?

Then she added that Buddha on the contrary believed that addition of one woman into the Sangha would make the Sangha last thousand years more.
There's orthodox text which says to the contrary -- i.e. according to AN 8.51:

Ānanda, if females had not gained the going forth from the lay life to homelessness in the teaching and training proclaimed by the Realized One, the spiritual life would have lasted long. The true teaching would have remained for a thousand years. But since they have gained the going forth, now the spiritual life will not last long. The true teaching will remain only five hundred years.

"Gotami" in that sutta is Mahapajapati Gotami.
What is the exact status of gender equality in Buddhism?
There are many Buddhists, and views and schools of Buddhism -- so there may be no "exact answer" to this question.
Even within Theravada, different monasteries of monks disagree with each other about whether it's possible for "a woman" to be ordained as a nun in modern times.

First of all, there are no men or women, no gender at all. Only arising and vanishing causes and effects.
So, what is real, arising and vanishing, more power to make the Sangha last thousand years more, is what the Buddha say.
It's like most people say Bitcoin is scam for years, but the truth is showing by Bitcoin's value through 10+ years.
Time proved the true value, isn't it?

Bitcoin has no intrinsic value, unlike real investments it's only worth what the market will pay. It's barely been around a decade, which isn't any evidence to prove true value.

Nibbana is only value because there is no other way to abandon the Suffering Dependent Origination and we going to die inside it cycle forever except Nibbana. I don't care of Bitcoin. I just learned how it works. And I just make it example to test the  reader mind power. If their meditation are not strong enough to read, they're going to miss the point.

You are making claims you don't have reasonable evidence for.

Do you understand the  world enough to talk about it? finance, money history, money supply, asset allocation, investment, economics, blockchain technology, decentralized vs centralized, war history, etc. If not, just focus on Nibbana, the only worth is Nibbana.

The Dhamma just has kamma and vippaka, cause and effect. Men and women are born so due to past actions and results. It is futile to think this means one is better then another, or that this relates to modern views. Each being is the owner of their kamma, and must evolve spiritually at their own pace.
While the suttas are clear on this topic:

“It is impossible and inconceivable, bhikkhus, that a woman could be an arahant who is a perfectly enlightened Buddha … (AN 1.279)

This just means that there are offices in rebirth (same as Mara, Brahma, Sakka...) that can not be taken up by a women. It does not mean that a women can not fill those positions in the future by determination.
Bhikkhu Bodhi states:

... the claim being made here is not that a woman cannot become a perfectly enlightened Buddha in a future life but that a Buddha is always male. (AN note 157)

DipaMa is quoted as saying that women can become Buddha’s (presumably meaning as a women) but the full context or quote could have been misunderstood or misquoted, as this is not on any recordings anywhere that I know of.
The quote your teacher was referring to is below:

“But, Ānanda, if women had not obtained the Going-forth from the home life into homelessness in the Dhamma and discipline made known by the Tathāgata, the holy life would have lasted long, the true Dhamma would have lasted 1,000 years. But now that they have gotten to go forth… this holy life will not last long, the true Dhamma will last only 500 years. Just as a clan in which there are many women and few men is easily plundered by robbers and thieves, in the same way, in whatever Dhamma and discipline women get to go forth from the home life into homelessness, the holy life does not last long… Just as a man might make an embankment in advance around a great reservoir to keep the waters from overflowing, in the same way I have set forth in advance the eight rules of respect for bhikkhunīs that they are not to transgress as long as they live.”—Cv.X.1

These are written (here with the Garudhammas). The Garudhammas were written as the precursor to women’s ordination, mentioned both in the Vinaya and the suttas [(AN 8.51])1.
In the Mahaparinibbana Sutta (DN 16) the four fold Sangha (monks, nuns, laymen and laywomen) is mentioned explicitly so it looks like Lord Buddha had expected the full spectrum of that assembly. So it seems that the Buddha did expect to have women ordination by seeing these quotes that mention the four fold assembly.
The classical Buddhistic ideas of men and women are often unpopular when contrasting with modern ideals. One example showing the differences of men and women, is the sufferings experienced by a women and not by a man. SN 47.3
Ultimately women and men both still need to practice. If one is to realise path and fruit in this life, or to be a Buddha in a future life, or advanced disciples, or fully enlightened, then spiritual practice and purity must still be won through one's own efforts. The Dhamma is that Light, that Guide, that Vehicle that we use to realise that end. We all have bones and suffering, and we have a human birth, so the opportunity to practice is the same.
Better to try to view the Dhamma in a wholesome light and see how it is personally applicable, rather then trying to change it to fit changing popular ideals. Modern technological world has allowed for these ideas, but are they helping us be better in our own practice.
A good example of the differences of men and women is in Lord Buddhas instructions to his disciples:
The Bhikkhus (monks) should emulate the lead bhikkhus...

“Bhikkhus, a bhikkhu endowed with faith, rightly aspiring, should aspire thus: ‘May I become like Sāriputta and Moggallāna!’ This is the standard and criterion for my bhikkhu disciples, that is, Sāriputta and Moggallāna.” (AN 1.30)

The Bhikkhunis (nuns) should emulate the lead bhikkhuni's...

“Bhikkhus, a bhikkhunī endowed with faith, rightly aspiring, should aspire thus: ‘May I become like the bhikkhunīs Khemā and Uppalavaṇṇā!’ This is the standard and criterion for my bhikkhunī disciples, that is, the bhikkhunīs Khemā and Uppalavaṇṇā.” (AN 1.31)

The lay male followers should emulate the lead lay male disciples...

“Bhikkhus, a male lay follower endowed with faith, rightly aspiring, should aspire thus: ‘May I become like Citta the householder and Hatthaka of Āḷavī!’ This is the standard and criterion for my male lay disciples, that is, Citta the householder and Hatthaka of Āḷavī.” (AN 1.32)

The lay female followers should emulate the lead lay female disciples...

“Bhikkhus, a female lay follower endowed with faith, rightly aspiring, should aspire thus: ‘May I become like the female lay followers Khujjuttarā and Veḷukaṇṭakī Nandamātā!’ This is the standard and criterion for my female lay disciples, that is, the female lay followers Khujjuttarā and Veḷukaṇṭakī Nandamātā.” (AN 1.33)

Thus working with our station of existence and our birth is not something that should cause problems. The goodness of the heart and the goodness of virtue travels even to the heavens.

... But the fragrance of the virtuous goes against the wind. The virtuous person pervades all directions with the fragrance of virtue.


... Of all the fragrances—sandal, tagara, blue lotus, and jasmine—the fragrance of virtue is by far the sweetest.


... but the fragrance of the virtuous is excellent, traveling even to the gods.

Dhammapada 54, 55, 56. (slightly altered)
The whole opportunity to practice as a human is very rare:

“Bhikkhus, suppose that this great earth had become one mass of water, and a man would throw a yoke with a single hole upon it. An easterly wind would drive it westward; a westerly wind would drive it eastward; a northerly wind would drive it southward; a southerly wind would drive it northward.
There was a blind turtle which would come to the surface once every hundred years. What do you think, bhikkhus, would that blind turtle, coming to the surface once every hundred years, insert its neck into that yoke with a single hole?”
“It would be by chance, venerable sir, that that blind turtle, coming to the surface once every hundred years, would insert its neck into that yoke with a single hole.”
“So too, bhikkhus, it is by chance that one obtains the human state; by chance that a Tathāgata, an Arahant, a Perfectly Enlightened One arises in the world; by chance that the Dhamma and Discipline proclaimed by the Tathāgata shines in the world.
“You have obtained that human state, bhikkhus; a Tathāgata, an Arahant, a Perfectly Enlightened One has arisen in the world; the Dhamma and Discipline proclaimed by the Tathāgata shines in the world.
“Therefore, bhikkhus, an exertion should be made to understand: ‘This is suffering.’… An exertion should be made to understand: ‘This is the way leading to the cessation of suffering.’”
[SN 56.48] (Copyright Wisdom Publication, listed here for study purposes only)

